# Continuous change in Sphinx Config File

Tags: sphinx

I am working on one project in which i have one Sphinx Config File.There are main four parts of Sphinx(source,index,indexer,searchd).In config file there is only one indexer and one searchd but source and index are multiple.Now i am starting searchd service over this config file.When new source and index added in config file, i notify searchd service with --rotate option in indexing to inform that new index is added over this service.But now suppose i am delete some source and index from config file.At that time i have to restart the searchd service to inform that particular index is no more in use.Is there any direct way to do this without restarting searchd service?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use

```
  kill -HUP `cat /path/to/sphinx.pid`
```

to tell Sphinx to reload current config